# Suppress Windows dialog in ShellLink Resolve with missing target in ShellLink?

Tags: shell, delphi, delphi-xe7

In Delphi XE7, I want to use the following code to replace the link target of a shell link file (.lnk):

```
uses
  JclShell;
...
procedure ShellLinkReplaceLinkTarget(const AShellLinkFile, ANewTarget: string);
var
  ThisShellLink: JclShell.TShellLink;
begin
  if (JclShell.ShellLinkResolve(AShellLinkFile, ThisShellLink) = S_OK) then // Windows error dialog
  begin
    ThisShellLink.Target := ANewTarget;
    JclShell.ShellLinkCreate(ThisShellLink, AShellLinkFile);
  end
    else CodeSite.Send('ShellLinkResolve Failed!');
end;
```

However, when the link target does not exist anymore, then at `ShellLinkResolve` the well known `Link problem` Windows error dialog comes up telling that the link target has been deleted etc. Here is the dialog in German:

[image]

So how can I suppress this dialog? Because the program needs to replace the missing link target with another one, not Windows.

Windows 7 x64 SP1

EDIT:

BTW: When I click on the `Restore` button (the leftmost button in the above dialog screenshot), then the missing target is restored from the waste basket - but the dialog is NOT being closed after the successful restore or at least the Restore button disabled after the restore. An example of bad UI design by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
if (JclShell.ShellLinkResolve(AShellLinkFile, ThisShellLink, 
  SLR_ANY_MATCH or SLR_NO_UI) = S_OK) then
```

Comment: The Windows dialog is now suppressed with `SLR_ANY_MATCH or SLR_NO_UI`, but `ShellLinkResolve` fails, while it does not fail when the link target exists. So it seems that Windows causes 2 things: Make `ShellLinkResolve` fail AND show the dialog. So now that the dialog is suppressed, `ShellLinkResolve` still fails.

Comment: Isn't that reasonable. If the target doesn't exist, wouldn't you expect resolve to fail. Docs are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774952(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have created a question arising from this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077977/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-shelllink-even-when-the-link-target-does-not-exist-an

Comment: Must `ThisShellLink` be freed after `ShellLinkResolve` when it is no longer used or can it be "left alone"?

Comment: To avoid memory leaks in case of successful result of ShellLinkResolve you must call ShellLinkFree at the end of your work with ThisShellLink.