# How to get the data from a ShellLink even when the Link Target does not exist anymore?

Tags: shell, delphi, delphi-xe7

In Delphi XE7, I wanted to use the following code to replace the link target of a shell link file (.lnk), even when the link target does not exist anymore:

```
uses
  JclShell;
...
procedure ShellLinkReplaceLinkTarget(const AShellLinkFile, ANewTarget: string);
var
  ThisShellLink: JclShell.TShellLink;
begin
  if (JclShell.ShellLinkResolve(AShellLinkFile, ThisShellLink, SLR_ANY_MATCH or SLR_NO_UI) = S_OK) then
  begin
    ThisShellLink.Target := ANewTarget;
    JclShell.ShellLinkCreate(ThisShellLink, AShellLinkFile);
  end
    else CodeSite.Send('ShellLinkResolve Failed!');
end;
```

Obviously, it is not possible to get the data from the Link file with `ShellLinkResolve` when the link target does not exist anymore, as David kindly explained.

So how can I get the data from the link file in this case?

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to resolve a link to something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Obviously, I misinterpreted the meaning of the word "Resolve" in this context. I believed that "Resolve" in this context means: simply getting the data stored inside the ShellLink. So I will rephrase the question to something like: "How can I get the data from the ShellLink file even when the target does not exist anymore?".

Comment: Looks like you need to call Resolve before you can do that. I suspect that if the link cannot be resolved, then you won't be able to read the information out. I think you'd be better off telling us about your underlying problem and then seeing if anyone (e.g. Dennis) can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why don`t you want to use very simple code like this:

```
procedure ShellLinkReplaceLinkTarget(const AShellLinkFile, ANewTarget: UnicodeString);
var
  ShellLink: IShellLinkW;
  PersistFile: IPersistFile;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IShellLinkW, ShellLink));
  try
    OleCheck(ShellLink.QueryInterface(IPersistFile, PersistFile));
    try
      OleCheck(PersistFile.Load(PWideChar(AShellLinkFile), STGM_READWRITE));
      OleCheck(ShellLink.SetIDList(nil));
      OleCheck(ShellLink.SetPath(PWideChar(ANewTarget)));
      OleCheck(PersistFile.Save(PWideChar(AShellLinkFile), True));
    finally
      PersistFile := nil;
    end;
  finally
    ShellLink := nil;
  end;
end;
```

And there is one very important detail. Some lnk files can contain different properties like background color (in Windows 8). And if you recreate lnk file properties will be lost.